# Representing heightmaps, on disk and when drawing

Tags: procedural-generation, level-design, heightmap

This is a conglomeration question when answering please specify which part you are addressing. I am looking at creating a maze type game that utilizes elevation. I have a few features I would like to have, but am unsure as to some of the implementation.

I have done work doing fileIO maze generation (using a key to read the file, and then generate the level based on that file), but I am unsure how to think about this with elevation in the mix. I think height maps might be a good approach, but don't know how to represent them effectively. for a height map which is more beneficial XML(containing h[u,v] data and key definition), CSV (item1 is key reference, item2 is elevation), or another approach that I have not thought of yet?

When it comes to placing the elevation values themselves what kind of `delta`h values are appropriate to have it noticeable at about a 60`degree` angle while not really effecting gravity driven physics (assuming some effect while moving up/down hill)?

I am thinking of maybe going to procedural generation at some point, but am wondering if it is practical to have a procedurally generated grid (wall squares possibly same dimensions as the open space squares), or if designing to a thin wall open spaces is better? this decision will effect the amount of work need on the graphics end for uniform vs. irregular walls.

EDIT: Game will be a elevation maze shooter. Levels/maps will be mazes with elevation the player has to negotiate. Elevations will have effects on "combat" vision, and movement.

Comment: Use an image file for the heightmap?

Comment: I think you need to read your question, then try re-writing it.

Comment: I am a bit of confused as to what kind of level/map you want, exactly. It would help if you specified desired output clearly and separately from the rest of the post.

Comment: @byte56 is there any section specifically that you are having trouble understanding

Comment: @superbest edited question. if not enough then i am unsure of what more to add without detailing my feature set.

Comment: Well, it's just my opinion, but I think this is a poor question. You're asking a lot of questions, and they are pretty vague questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking of maybe going to procedural generation at some point,
>   but am wondering if it is practical to have a procedurally generated
>   grid (wall squares possibly same dimensions as the open space
>   squares), or if designing to a thin wall open spaces is better?

Depending on how you go about things, I'd say it doesn't matter - either is good. Nethack and many roguelikes are a great example of how "fat walls" look when generating mazes/dungeons at a single height. I think it might possibly make your job easier, since all you need to store the level data is one array (as opposed to essentially two different arrays with thin walls: One for "inside-grid-cells" and one for "between-grid-cells") although Nethack is only one height.

I think you should start with whichever one is less work (probably fat walls), because honestly to a gamer what matters more is that the games logic is consistent and well-implemented rather than realistic; so it doesn't matter that fat-walls seem weird so long as they work and are bug-free.

> I think height maps might be a good approach

They aren't. If your maze is a bunch of rectangular (or polygonal) prismatic rooms connected by hallways, a heightmap is quite unsuitable. This is because you give up some huge things: Rooms cannot ever be above each other for instance, because for every z-level there is only one value. The heightmap, in other words, is a function, which can have only one output for a given input, this is quite an illogical constraint (why should it be the case?).

I say this especially because if you accept that assumption, your question becomes trivial. Just generate a 2D flat map as usual, generate (randomly?) a height for each room, flood fill, paint gradients in connecting hallways, done. Then, yes, perhaps a "heightmap" is appropriate as you say.

An alternative way of representing is to simply keep a list of tiles which have walls. The coordinates are 3D, because you'd need a 3D grid for storing a 3D level.

Comment: on your statement of holding the list of tiles. wouldn't it be more advantageous to hold a list of walls, and floors then the adjacent tiles there of, and wouldn't that also allow for holding blocks of different dimensions. though slopes might still be interesting